# Como esperar pelo resultado de uma Restful API no NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Trabalho com uma API JSON da Amazon, no qual pesquiso os produtos e trato as informações de acordo com os resultados dela, mas dentro do NodeJS as informações da API são escritas no console, mas não são escritas na resposta a chamada. Como responder só após os dados retornados da Amazon?

Segue o exemplo do código:

```
var http = require("http");
//Biblioteca para conexão e pesquisa nos servidores da Amazon 
var aws = require("aws-lib");

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
    var prodAdv = aws.createProdAdvClient(yourAccessKeyId, yourSecretAccessKey, yourAssociateTag);
    var options = {SearchIndex: "Books", Keywords: "Javascript"};
    var resposta = "";
    prodAdv.call("ItemSearch", options, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
        resposta = result;
    });
    res.end(resposta);
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

PS: Os parâmetros da função `createProdAdvClient` foram alterados por questões de segurança, para todos os efeitos estão preenchidos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os serviços da AWS são intrinsecamente Assíncronos. Das duas uma, ou você adota este paradigma ou deve usar uma biblioteca ou módulo do Node JS que transforma deste paradigma **assíncrono** para um **síncrono**.

Se você desejar usar um paradigma síncrono então pode testar com o Step

> A simple control-flow library for node.JS that makes parallel
>   execution, serial execution, and error handling painless.

Use a opção Serial Execution

Veja um exemplo abaixo:

A function `Step` do [módulo step](https://github.com/creationix/step) aceita qualquer número de funções com seus argumentos e executa de forma serial em ordem usando o `this` e passando para a nova função no proximo passo.

```
Step(
  function readSelf() {
    fs.readFile(__filename, this);
  },
  function capitalize(err, text) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return text.toUpperCase();
  },
  function showIt(err, newText) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(newText);
  }
);
```

Observe que o `this` é passado na função `fs.readFile`. Quando a leitura do arquivo termina a função `Step` envia o resultado como argumento para a proxima function da cadeia. Em seguida o valor retornado por `capitalize` é passado para `showIt` que exibe o resultado.

Com isso conseguimos encadear sincronamente a execução dos métodos.

Comment: Este problema de entendimento do paradigma assincrono é tão comum que se você pesquisar por `Synchronize asynchronous calls in node` no Google vai encontrar diversas implementações de módulos que endereçam este problema.

Answer (score 1):

```
prodAdv.call("ItemSearch", options, function(err, result) {
console.log(result);
    resposta = result;
});
res.end(resposta);
```

*Você quis dizer:* (simplifiquei o código e arrumei o erro da utilização da [http](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html))

```
prodAdv.call("ItemSearch", options, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {throw err;}
  console.log(result);
  res.write(result);
  res.end();
});
```

Comment: Vale mencionar a causa do problema: a chamada do serviço é assíncrona, e a requisição está sendo encerrada antes que a resposta chegue.

Comment: A indenização está confusa e está usando métodos assíncronos como não fossem. Por mim pareceu só falta de organização, que gerou a confusão, ou um exemplo mal copiado, por exemplo de um que usa buffers.

Comment: Não o problema está na assincronicidade mesmo. Preciso de um jeito para que o servidor responda somente depois da resposta dos servidores da Amazon.
@GustavoRodrigues Já tentei o exemplo que você comentou antes e problema persiste.

Comment: Acabei de testar no node é parece que era um erro na utilização do módulo/função http.

Comment: Gustavo eu consegui, utilizar a solução apresentada, o conceito estava em responder na função de Callback mesmo.